# Unable to connect to the Internet

Tags: networking

Hi I am unable to connect to the internet.

Have setup my configurations like this:

```
IP address 192.168.2.51
Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0
Default Route 192.168.2.1
DNS 192.168.2.10
```

Comment: Need more information. Run the command `ip addr` and post the output. Are you sure you connected everything right ?

Comment: I am very new to Ubuntu I am unable to copy the configuration

Comment: need more information like are u connected directory are using any router in-between etc..!

Comment: Open a terminal window with CTRL+ALT+T. Copy the command to run and paste it into the terminal. Always use the mouse when copying from/pasting to the terminal, as e.g. CTRL+C has a different meaning there: it will kill the currently running command. So right-click instead and select "Paste" from the context menu. Hit ENTER. After the command finished, select the output lines with the mouse, right-click, select "Copy", then [edit] your question, paste the output, select it again and hit CTRL+K or click the **`{}`** button for proper formatting.

Comment: I am connected to a router yes , the idea is to get my Ubuntu machine to the internet . I use the same settings to connect to my windows machine and the settings works but the settings don't work on my Ubuntu machine

Comment: have not connected my Ubuntu machine with putty , so its very hard for me to send you the settings

Comment: Are you sure the IP range is right?  Typically, I see routers using 192.168 to have the 192.168.1 range, not the 192.168.2 range.

Comment: @user465610 is the Windows machine using the same IP address at the same time? If so, that's not allowed; you would need to choose a different IP address. I suggest you open `Terminal` and type `ping -c 5 192.168.2.1` to see if your router is reachable, and copy/paste the result into this question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but if you can connect to the network but not internet you should try adding a names servers.

Try adding the Google nameservers to the bottom of the config file in `/etc/hosts`

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Make sure to restart your computer or reset network connection by running the commands below

```
ifdown lo 
ifup lo
```

Comment: @user465610 Im glad your issues are resolved. If this helped resolve your issue please accept it as an answer to help out the next person with this issue.